# Unanswered questions have accepted answer with upvote in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, unanswered-questions, android-app-feed

I see some of the questions in the Unanswered section having an accepted answer and the accepted answer having upvote also in the Android app.

In the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) post it is defined as

> **Unanswered questions** have no answers with upvotes (or accepted)

But the accepted answer with upvote also still list in the Unanswered questions. Is my understanding is wrong or is it a bug?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Unanswered with accepted and upvote]

Comment: One of [many. many, old bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-app%5D+%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-planned%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D+closed%3A0) (380 and counting) that exist since the very beginning of the app.

Comment: This is due to caching of the feed, the items are determined when they are added into the feed and not checked again for their status each time they're shown.