# Can we contribute to solve the older bugs in the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app

I know that [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183995/can-i-contribute-to-the-stack-exchange-source-code#answer-183997) was already asked here three years ago but bugs in the app are is still there.

Today I downloaded the Android app and found a bug. Then I tried to report that bug but I found that bug was [already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273351/unanswered-questions-have-accepted-answer-with-upvote-in-android-app) more than a year ago.

I know that Stack Exchange is a private company so it will not allow us to do the same but we all know that  Stack Overflow is the largest community of software engineers in the world and they are genius or good enough to fix any bug, so why does our app have still the bug?

Here I said "our" app because I believe that I'm part of the Stack Exchange community. As a software engineer I don't want to see any bugs in my app.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272122/why-has-stack-exchange-stopped-working-on-the-android-app

Comment: Also: *I don't want to see any bugs in my app* I don't want to sound pessimistic but industry average is 15-50 defects per 1000 lines of code...

Comment: The app code is not open source, so the default and rather short answer would be "no". To change that approach would be a very large decision that would take a lot of consideration and discussion and team organisation / restructuring and legals and ... and ... yeah, that's not simple.